# If/then statement on field value in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, if-statement, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm trying to write a statment that looks at the value in a boolean field (field_solo) and returns one of two template files that I have created in Drupal 7.

My field "field_solo" is correctly outputting a value of 0 or 1 and I have cleared the cache.

Can someone tell me if I am doing this correctly? Right now I am not getting it to display when the statement is TRUE.

```
function motg_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

$node = $vars['node'];
  if($node->field_solo[0]['value'] == 1)
  {
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'node__solo';
  } else
  {
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'node__video';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if($node->field_solo[0]['value'] == 1)
```

Make it

```
if($node->field_solo['und'][0]['value'] == 1)
// OR
if($node->field_solo[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == 1)
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks Muhammad! I'll accept the answer when I can.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the above is not the standard Drupal way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this it could be helpful:
http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
<?php if ($content["field_hide_title"]["#items"][0]["value"] == 0) { ?>
<?php echo $node->title; ?></h2>
<?php } ?>
```